# Unable to run app with app Extension Embedded binary is not signed with the same certificate as the parent app

Tags: ios, ios-app-extension

I am getting below error when added `BroadCastExtension` to my app. I am using this BroadCastExtension for screen share.

> Embedded binary is not signed with the same certificate as the parent app. Verify the embedded binary target's code sign settings match the parent app's.

I have changes all possible solution mention on StackOverflow or apple Development, But no luck.

I am using bundle id for parent app is `com.sdkapp`
where I am using bundle id for broadcast extension is - `com.sdkapp.BroadCastExtension`

Both has the code signing as apple development

did I do any things wrong?

Answer (score 0):

To Fixed this issue,

Delete the app Extension from the app target and unselect from manage schemes.
Clear the drive data, and add the app extension again back.

Note:- Do not copy past from old app Extension classes.